# Probability Lottery Question With Unknown Total Tickets

Tags: probability

If I have $3$ tickets for a lottery for which $n$ tickets were sold and $5 $ prizes are to be given, what is the probability that you will win at least one prize?

Comment: 1 winning ticket is equivalent to 1 prize right?

Comment: One ticket is equal to one prize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you say, each winning ticket is equivalent to one prize, and we don't know the exact $5$ winning lottery tickets.

So, we can choose the $5$ winning tickets from $n$ tickets in $^nC_5$ ways.

Now, Let's say you don't want to win the lottery. In order to achieve that, you **must not** have the winning cards. So, as you have $3$ with you, keep them aside.

We still have $(n - 3)$ tickets left. Now, we can tell with **certainty** that $5$ of these $(n - 3)$ tickets are the winning ones.

We can choose them in $^{n - 3}C_5$ ways.

That means, the probability of those 5 cards belonging to the group of the $(n-3)$ tickets you don't have is $$\frac{^{n-3}C_5}{^nC_5}$$

So, the probability of you **having** the lottery = $1 - \frac{^{n-3}C_5}{^nC_5}$ as the sum of the probabilities of all possible events is always $1$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the complementary event.

The probaibilty is $\displaystyle 1-\frac{n-3 \choose 5}{n \choose 5}$.

Comment: Fix the spelling mistake please.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, there are $n(n-1)(n-2)$ ways to choose $3$ different tickets.  And there are $(n-5)(n-6)(n-7)$ ways to choose a ticket that not wins.  Hence
$$1-\frac{(n-5)(n-6)(n-7)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}$$
is the chance to win at least one price.